# jquery selectors can't select Raphaeljs's path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, raphael

I'm building a scroller in my SVG. I'm using this as well http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/s5mgX/

The id of the path is assigned as so in another function:

```
  scrolldown.node.setAttribute("id","scrollDown");
```

the JQuery:

```
 $("#scrollDown").bind("click", function(event) {event.preventDefault();
/*function here..........*/}
```

even if I use `$("path").` It seems to not recognize it.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong? 
How do I set the click to trigger correctly with JQuery?

Comment: Have you verified that the setAttribute is working?  I recall having issues dynamically setting IDs on the client.  Try using a "name" attribute instead maybe?

Comment: yes I did, the Id is set properly

Comment: <path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" fill="#f4e3ff" stroke="#000000" d="M135.70635094610964,210L151.55444566227678,237.5L281.45825622994255,237.5L297.30635094610966,210Z" id="scrollDown"></path>

Comment: Some things to check: are you doing the bind *after* the SVG has loaded? Is there more than one path with `id=scrollDown` in your html which could be confusing JQuery?

Comment: I added document ready, still don't work, there is only one id of "scrollDown". I'm doing a lot of panning and zooming with the viewBox, might that be the cause?

Comment: ok it worked. the jquery did ran before the path was created.
but now it's really slow, wonder why...